# start: Unknown job: uwsgi

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-14.04, uwsgi

I am beginner in use server!
I use this website for install my application.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

I did **step by step** instructions, but not work, just show "Welcome to nginx!"

There is no error, but I think that does not work uWSGI.

```
sudo service nginx configtest: [OK]
sudo service nginx restart: [OK]
sudo service uwsgi start: "start: Unknown job: uwsgi"
```

thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo update
sudo upgrade
```

All instructions must be done carefully!
Great tutorial!